# Ruby Sequel error, table already exists

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

I realized that I can't run the tutorial (http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) twice.

The first time, it runs as we expect. But the second time, it raises an error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table `items` already exists (Sequel::DatabaseError)
```

I understand the error, but I don't know how to fix it.

How can I open the DB without losing the data it contains, and still being able to run the tutorial?

Comment: In this case you can take a backup of data and drop the table and create again Table and import your backup data

Comment: NO! That's terrible! What if you have 10 GB? You can't wait for that twice (when you backup it, and when you import it)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is, it tries to create a DB with the same name, but it already exists, so it raises an error.

Solution:

- `create_table` Try to create the table, raise an error if already exists.
- `create_table!` Drop the table if exists, and then create the table (YOU LOSE YOUR DATA).
- `create_table?` Create the table only if it doesn't exist.